# How to save my website form in to salesforce custom object as record? ---Need Help

Tags: apex, visualforce, soap, rest

I have a form in my website(Example : Application for applying the Job).when the user  fill the form in our website  and submits.A record should be created in the custom object.

Comment: what language you are using for your website?

Comment: yes. we are using PHP language for our website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce provides [PHP SDK](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP) which can be used to interact with Salesforce from your PHP application.

1. Download PHP SDK
2. Put SOAPClient in your root folder.
3. Download partner.wsdl.xml from your Salesforce setup-> Develop -> API and put that in root folder as well.
4. Create new PHP file create.php and copy following code.
5. replace UserName and password value with your credentials.
6. Pass your form values to this file

Sample code:

```
<?php
require_once ('soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php');    
try {
       $USERNAME='YOURSFDCUSERNAME';
       $PASSWORD ='YOURSALESFORCEPASSWORD+SECURITYTOKEN';
       $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
       $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection('partner.wsdl.xml');
       $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

  $fields = array (
    'FirstName' => 'John',
    'LastName' => 'Smith',
    'Phone' => '510-555-5555',
    'BirthDate' => '1950-01-01'
  );

  $sObject = new SObject();
  $sObject->fields = $fields;
  $sObject->type = 'Contact';

  echo "**** Creating the following:\r\n";
  $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject));

  print_r($createResponse);


} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $mySforceConnection->getLastRequest();
  echo $e->faultstring;
}
?>
```

You can go through other sample code here

[Salesforce PHP SDK samples](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Samples)

Comment: Hi Himanshu, i have downloaded the PHP SDK Tool kit from the salesforce .what would be the next step to take .As i am new to this development  and i dont know PHP. Can you please give me the detailed instructions .Thank you

Comment: i have updated question with instruction but as you don't know PHP it can be hard for you to understand because it need some knowledge of PHP. you can contact your php developer to complete this task

Comment: we don't have a PHP Developer Himanshu....

Comment: Hi Himanshu,  I have an Php form ...Lets say First Name,Last name and there are around 20 fields on the application from.when the users fills the  values in the form and  clicks submit. How to pass the values to the Php code (Above) so that it creates the record in salesforce with all those values